# Preventing underflows when computing log of the probability that a normal sample falls in a certain interval in python

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, numerical-computing

Given two reals `x` and `y`,  I want to compute the following function in python:

```
log Pr [ x <= t <= y ],
```

where `t` is sampled from a normal distribution.

One naive implementation is to use [`scipy.stats.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

```
np.log(scipy.stats.norm.cdf(y) - scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x))
```

Unfortunately, this causes an underflow when `x` and `y` are far from `0`.
How can one prevent such a numerical error?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is much more stable if done in logspace.

The trick is to use `scipy.stats.norm.logcdf` for values less than zero and `scipy.stats.norm.logsf` for values larger than zero.

This combined with a stable algorithm for calculating `log(exp(y) - exp(x))` gives reasonable results

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def log_subtract(x, y):
    return x + np.log1p(-np.exp(y-x))

def lnprob(x, y):
    if x < 0:
        return log_subtract(norm.logcdf(y), norm.logcdf(x))
    else:
        return log_subtract(norm.logsf(x), norm.logsf(y))
```